# Stepper driver - pinout: enable, reset and sleep

Tags: stepper-motor, pins, stepper-driver

Can anybody tell me (as simple as can) what is actual difference between:
ENABLE, RESET and SLEEP pin on DRV8825 stepper motor driver ?

I'm trying to learn programing by writing simple CNC controller.
And I want to disable stepper driver and motor for time when user will be in configuration menu.

I already have read datasheet, but it's still unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8825.pdf

This data sheet contains all valid information which you are asking, and it is well evolved to understand any beginner who have knowledge of stepper motor operation.